# Is there a simple way to change the origin point of a lot of objects at once?

Tags: interface, objects

I have a piano keyboard, so there are 88 individual keys. Unfortunately, I left the origins in the centers of each key. As a result, I can't rotate them properly. I could go through each one and manually correct each key, but that would be a huge pain. Is there a way to set them all at once? (I only need to move the x location on each key, in case that makes a difference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use the same technique as above but instead of doing it to each key individually you could use the [Multi Edit addon](http://blenderaddonlist.blogspot.ru/2014/06/addon-multi-edit.html) and shift the geometry of your keys then counter the movement in object mode.

Also back up your scene before you try the addon (still in Alpha stage) just to be safe.

Answer (score 6):

1. Select all your piano keys.
2. Set your 3D cursor to the location where you want your point of rotation.
3. Object -> Transform -> Origin To 3D Cursor

That will set the origin for all the piano keys at once.

Comment: I guess what I really wanted was a way to just shift the origins up along the X-axis. I don't want them all to be in the same exact spot. I went ahead and did it manually anyway, so it's kind of a moot point now.

Comment: To get all origins in a position other than centre of geometry you would need to do each manually or use a script.

Answer (score 1):

You can also move the objects in object mode, then counter the movement in edit mode, This probably won't be less work, but I'm adding this for the sake of completeness.

A Gif showing the process.
[image]